# Entity Framework - Validation error on entity read at Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6

From yesterday i am struggling with that strange error. Localhost deploy works fine, but few hours after deploy on Azure i get

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

It's happen when i enter to my controller registration action on fetching :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        Wallet stockMarketWallet = walletRepository.GetMarketWallet(); // here it comes
        RegisterViewModel vm = new RegisterViewModel();
        vm.UserStocks = new List<UserStockViewModel>();

        foreach (UserStock stock in stockMarketWallet.OwnedStocks)
        {
            vm.UserStocks.Add(new UserStockViewModel {
                StockId = stock.StockId,
                Code = stock.Stock.Code
            });
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Internal Error details says that UserApplications not unique username is rising ValidationError.

**WalletRepository**

```
public class WalletRepository : IWalletRepository
{
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public WalletRepository()
        => context = ApplicationContext.Create();

    public Wallet GetMarketWallet()
    {
        string stockMarketUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StockMarketUsername"];
        return context.Wallets.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ApplicationUser.UserName.Equals(stockMarketUserName));
    }

    ...
}
```

}

**Wallet**

```
public class Wallet
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string WalletId { get; set; }

    public decimal Founds { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserStock> OwnedStocks { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public Wallet()
    {
        OwnedStocks = new List<UserStock>();
    }

    ...
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
}
```

What is even stranger to me after cloning Azure database to localhost it works fine too.

Comment: Try to check the validation error. See @wizzardz answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020947/how-do-i-check-entityvalidationerrors-when-validation-fails

Comment: I wrote, it's unique username validation error, but how can it ocure during reading?

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I have developed a test demo on my computer, it works well.

I suggest you could create a new azure sql database and use its connection string directly in the local to test again.

More details about my test demo, you could refer to below codes:

IdentityModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public virtual Wallet Wallet { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public DbSet<Wallet> Wallets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserStock> UserStocks { get; set; }

}
```

Wallet.cs

```
public class Wallet
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string WalletId { get; set; }

    public decimal Founds { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserStock> OwnedStocks { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public Wallet()
    {
        OwnedStocks = new List<UserStock>();
    }     
}
```

WalletRepository.cs

```
public class WalletRepository
{
    public ApplicationDbContext context;

    public WalletRepository() { context = ApplicationDbContext.Create(); }

    public Wallet GetMarketWallet()
    {
        string stockMarketUserName = "The user name";
        return context.Wallets.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ApplicationUser.UserName.Equals(stockMarketUserName));
    }


}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //Add test record
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext d1 = new ApplicationDbContext();          
        ApplicationUser user = d1.Users.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserName.Equals("UserName"));
        Wallet w1 = new Wallet();
        w1.ApplicationUser = user;
        w1.Founds = 300;
        UserStock u1 = new UserStock();
        u1.id = 1;
        List<UserStock> l1 = new List<UserStock>();
        l1.Add(u1);
        w1.WalletId = user.Id;
        d1.Wallets.Add(w1);
        d1.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Message = "Add Completed";
        return View();
    }

    //Call the Repository to get the value
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        WalletRepository walletRepository = new WalletRepository();
        var result = walletRepository.GetMarketWallet();
        ViewBag.Message = "WalletId : " + result.WalletId;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

If this is still generate the error, please the details information about the error message.

Comment: Its quite odd, because i quite changed it. Instead of have same primary key for both wallet and user, i add own primary key to wallet (WalletId) and Foreign Key for ApplicationUser, then i made fluent api mapping, and now everything works fine.